# Como iterar sobre duas coleções de objetos diferentes com laço de repetição

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou construindo uma aplicação e basicamente eu tenho duas coleções de objetos diferentes e agora preciso usar um laço de repetição para iterar sobre as duas porém preciso pegar dados de uma coleção e depois e dados da outra coleção e exibir para o usuário. Como posso iterar sobre as duas com o laço For Of? Existe essa possibilidade?

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor proveito do site.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Podes concatenar os arrays.

```
var arr = arr1.concat(arr2);
```